# What is the LINQ for getting a string of concatenated values for a input string with concatenated codes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

1. I have a column called `MultipleErrorTypeID` which will have error codes like `5,34,1` and so on. It is a concatenation of a list of error codes, separated by commas.
2. I want to write a LINQ expression which splits this string, validates them against a Master called `ErrorTypes`, the Primary key being `ErrorTypes.ErrorTypeID` and gets back a set of `ErrorTypeName`, again concatenated with commas, into a string called `ErrorType`.
3. I came upto  this stage and got stuck

   ```
   ErrorType = (from err in db.ErrorTypes 
                let tmp = prd.MultipleErrorTypeID.Split(',')
                where err.ErrorTypeID == tmp. (how to iterate through this and how to combine the result into the string called ErrorType)
   ```

Comment: what is the problem, that did you expect?

Comment: What is `prd` ? is that an object retrieved earlier ?

Comment: @Batavia I wasn't sure how to loop through the items in tmp, and how to put back the results into another string with comma seperators.

Comment: Yes @Habib, prd is a Production table  "var query = (from prd in db.Productions"

Comment: @Chakra, but that is not part of your current query in question, how would you have access to `prd` in your current query ?

Comment: @Habib i am trying to write a sub query in a larger query. The var has already been populated from prd - i am just trying to fill in one part of the larger query. I did not paste the larger query since it is too large.

Comment: @Chakra, try adding an minimal example of your sub query which is replicating the issue, because the answers below assumed that `prd` is  an object already populated in memory and not part of query.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to split the string outside of the LINQ statement:

```
 var codes =  prd.MultipleErrorTypeID.Split(',');

 var query = from err in db.ErrorTypes 
        where codes.Contains(err.ErrorTypeID)
        select err.ErrorTypeName;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you all the error strings in a single string.

```
var errCodes=  prd.MultipleErrorTypeID.Split(',');

string errors = String.Join(",", db.ErrorTypes
                                   .Where(et => errCodes
                                   .Contains(et.ErrorTypeID))
                                   .Select(et => et.ErrorTypeName));
```